# How to find developer partner with lots of users

Tags: cleos, wallet, ram-allocation

I am running a blockchain chinese news website and a cryptocurrency data website. So i have lots of users and chat group.  How can i find the good developers to develop the EOS toolit or wallet?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a telegram group.

https://t.me/eos_jobs

It is not yet active, but more people are gathering.